# R: Replace values of dataframe from another using row/column

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe` that I want to replace some of its values using another `dataframe` which I have `row`, `column`, and `value` information.

```
dat <- data.frame(Age = c(19,22,32,24),Names = c("Bobby","Mary","Bill","Chuck"), Sport = c("Golf","Tennis","Football","Soccer"))

  Age Names    Sport
   19 Bobby     Golf
   22  Mary   Tennis
   32  Bill Football
   24 Chuck   Soccer

valuesreplace <- data.frame(row = c(1,3), column = c(3,1), value = c("Basketball","18"))

  row column      value
    1      3 Basketball
    3      1         18
```

The result should be the following:

```
  Age Names      Sport
   19 Bobby Basketball
   22  Mary     Tennis
   18  Bill   Football
   24 Chuck     Soccer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to first convert the `factor` to `character` (use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while constructing both data.frames) and then use pass a `matrix` of row/column index select the values of 'dat' and assign values from 'valuesreplace' column 'value'

```
dat[as.matrix(valuesreplace[1:2])] <- valuesreplace$value
dat
#  Age Names      Sport
#1  19 Bobby Basketball
#2  22  Mary     Tennis
#3  18  Bill   Football
#4  24 Chuck     Soccer
```

Comment: Holy response time! Yes, that works perfectly and good tip on converting `factor` to `character`. (I'll accept in 10 minutes when it lets me)